# Can't create linebreak between rows of a cases environment

Tags: equations, cases

I have this code:

```
\begin{equation}
f_k(x) =\begin{cases}
\mu (z)-z_k  \mathrm{\  if} \ k = \mathrm{arg \ min_j} \|  c^{(j)}-x \|_2^2
\\
0 \quad \mathrm{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Which correctly produces this output in one of my documents:
[image]

However when I copy and paste that code into a template I was given, it ignores the line break and looks like this:
[image]

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean? Like add \begin{document} and stuff?

Comment: Yes, such that we can copy and paste it and use as is. We don't know your preamble or document class

Comment: Oh in looking for that stuff I realized that my problem was that I was missing amsmath package from my template. I added it and now it works. Should I update my question and mark it resolved or just delete it?

Comment: @user1816679 You have an answer, no need to delete your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to (a) loading the `amsmath` package and (b) providing a `\\` line-break directive, two things you appear to have done since you first posted your query, I would also (c) use `\text` instead of `\mathrm`, (d) define `\argmin` as a math-operator macro, (e) use `&` to line up the conditioning statements and (f, optional) load the `mathtools` package in order to be able to define a `\norm` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads "amsmath" automatically
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
f_k(x) =
\begin{cases}
  \mu (z)-z_k & \text{if $k = \argmin_j \norm[\big]{c^{(j)}-x}_2^2 $} \\ 
  0           & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you are loading `mathtools`, using the `dcases*` environment will spare you the `\text` commands (I’m sure you knew this! :-)

Comment: @GuM - Good catch! :-) I started with `cases` and switched to `dcases` late in the game, after having written the `\text` stuff. I'll revert to cases...

Comment: No—I meant `dcases*`, or, if you prefer, `cases*`, which, in this case (!), is just the same.  It’s not the `d` that matters, but the `*`.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve suggested the following slight variation of [@Mico’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402634) in a couple of comments, but since my suggestion appears to have been declined, I’m posting it as an alternative answer.

The `mathtools` package defines a whole family of variants of the `cases` environement, which are described in section 3.4.3 (on p. 18) of its manual.  Each member of the family has a “starred” variant in which the second column is set in text mode, rather than in math mode: this spare you the nuisance of having to repeat `\text{...}` in every row.  For example, in our case we could replace the `cases` environment with `cases*`, as the following code illustrates:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads "amsmath" automatically

\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}



\begin{document}

Some text to begin with.
\begin{equation}
    f_k(x) =
        \begin{cases*}
            \mu (z)-z_k & if \( k = \argmin_j \norm[\big]{c^{(j)}-x}_2^2 \) \\
            0           & otherwise
        \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\slshape

The \texttt{cases*} environment, as well as the other ``starred'' variant forms
of the \texttt{cases} environment, import the font setting of the surrounding
text, exactly as the \verb|\text| command does.
\begin{equation}
    f_k(x) =
        \begin{cases*}
            \mu (z)-z_k & if \( k = \argmin_j \norm[\big]{c^{(j)}-x}_2^2 \) \\
            0           & otherwise
        \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here’s the output you get:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: +1 for `cases*`.